# Double spaced footnotes with \autocite[]{} and \footnote{} in it

Tags: footnotes, biblatex-chicago

I searched but not found a solution. I have to write a thesis and do this with article `biblatex-chicago`. This generate all ok, but the footnotes and bibtex entries (citations) within a footnote are single spaced between each. I need to have a double space between each footnote (not within a single footnote or a citation, rather every new footnote).

Answer (score 1):

Just found it:

```
\setlength{\footnotesep}{\baselineskip}
```